# How to allow users to Upload local file, Edit in sheets, and Write back to local file

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm investigating if it's possible for a user to: Pick a file on disk, automatically upload it to Google Sheets, do some edits, and write the changes back to the file.
I basically want to use Google Sheets as the Editor of the local file.

*Has anyone tried something like this, or can confirm if it's a feasible idea?*

My rough idea:

1. Install a script or program, that a user (on our team) can execute with the appropriate file they pick.
2. Typically they right-click a file and pick *"Open with MyGoogleSheetsCreate"*.
3. The *ToSheets*-script does the following:

   1. Generates a temporary Spreadsheet on the user's Google Drive (or possibly a Team Drive/Folder for temp files)
   2. Reads the custom data in the local file and enters it into the Spreadsheet.
   3. Opens a Browser window with the generated spreadsheet.
4. The user makes some changes to the spreadsheet.
5. The user exports the changes back to the file.

   1. User initiates this how? Some ideas:

      1. *Perferably:* I build a button or menu option to "Export back to Local Disk". This would only be viable if we could explicitly say where to save this custom file, i.e. where it came from.
      2. *Optionally:* They right-click the original file and pick "Open with MyGoogleSheetsRetrieve". The importer would need to know the address of the Google Sheet the local file was last exported to.
   2. FromSheets-Script converts the Spreadsheet into our custom data format and overwrites the old file.
6. *Bonus:* The temporary Google Sheet would be automatically moved to the Bin within a couple of days (without user interaction).

I think I've got a good idea of how to convert our custom format to Sheets and vice versa. **The steps I'm most unsure of are: 3.1 and 5.1**

Comment: [*Why?*](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: Why? I can see many applications, but in our specific case we have a Git repository where the data files must reside. We could work offline with the local files, then the options become 1: Use an offline spreadsheet tool (e.g. OpenOffice) which everyone needs to install/update/configure etc. 2: Write our own Spreadsheet tool.

Comment: Also, the period where it's on Google Drive, people could collaborate on the file and make changes together.